# Make photo tags visible in my profile without including old photos

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-tags

In the past I disabled the option of showing photos that I was tagged in on my profile. Now that facebook introduced the option of first approving tags before they are placed on your profile, I would like to enable them. But when I turn this feature on, I suddenly get all photos I was ever tagged in on my profile. Is there a way to turn on this "approve tags" feature without automatically approving all my old photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to be the answer you'd like to here but sadly no. It's not possible. That setting only works going forward so you'll need to sort out your old tags manually.

Comment: That's too bad :(